# Invalid DICT array size (83::2) in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, adobe

[image]

What does the error "After Effects error: invalid DICT array size (83::2)" mean?
Is this a serious problem?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This in essence is a font system error.

If your system was working fine and then after installing some fonts you are getting this error, I would uninstall the fonts in question.

Fonts that have special characters in their internal font names (not the fontfile name) like accents, umlauts or trademark signs will cause this issue and need to be removed.

The update to After Effects CC 12.1 should fix this error. http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2013/09/after-effects-cc-12-1-whats-new-and-changed.html